# How does assigning to `uint` save "storage read" costs in Ethereum?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm taking a look at the uniswapv2 tutorial [walkthrough](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/uniswap-v2-annotated-code/).

The followng is in reference to this function [in the github repo](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/4dd59067c76dea4a0e8e4bfdda41877a6b16dedc/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol#L92) and the tutorial states the following:

```
    uint _kLast = kLast; // gas savings
```

> The kLast state variable is located in storage, so it will have a
> value between different calls to the contract. Access to storage is a
> lot more expensive than access to the volatile memory that is released
> when the function call to the contract ends, so we use an internal
> variable to save on gas.

So in traditional programming, `_kLast` would be a reference to `kLast`. `_kLast` is referenced 3 more times after it's instantiation.

- Had they used just `kLast` as the variable, and not assigned it to `uint`, would it cost a storage read each time `kLast` is used?
- If this is NOT the case, then I really don't understand how they're saving on gas, can someone explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each storage read (opcode `sload`) of the same slot costs 2,100 gas the first time during a transaction, and then 100 gas each other time during the same transaction. (After the [EIP-2929](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2929) implemented in the Berlin hardfork. Before that, it was 800 for each read no matter how many times you performed the reads.)

Each memory write (opcode `mstore`) and each memory read (opcode `mload`) cost 3 gas.

---

> *So in traditional programming, `_kLast` would be a reference to `kLast`*

In this particular Solidity snippet, `_kLast` is not a reference pointing to the storage. It's a memory variable that has value assigned from the storage variable.

So 3 storage reads - not creating the memory variable - would cost 2,300 gas (= 2,100 + 100 + 100).

But because the code creates the memory variable, it performs one storage read (2,100 gas), one memory write (3 gas), and three memory reads (3 x 3 gas) - totalling 2,112 gas. Which is a cheaper option.

---

Some other EVM-compatible networks, such as BSC, might still use the original gas calculation of 800 per each `sload`. Which would make even larger difference - non-optimized 2,400 gas (3 x 800), and optimized 812 gas (800 + 3 + 3x3).